# Placement of COD and COI in one sentence

Tags: pronoms-personnels

When you have this sentence: He has said it to me.
Would this be 'il me l'a dit' or 'il le m'a dit'?

Comment: This can be easily researched not only from existing answers but from many other Internet resources.

Comment: "*Il me l'a dit*"!